# Selecting PostGIS objects out of given distance

Tags: qgis, postgis

I need to select by SQL querry objects that are further than 100m from specific type of road. For selecting object that are in given distance there is `ST_DWithin` but what to do in this case?

Comment: Have you tried NOT ST_DWithin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ST_DWithin returns a boolean value, so condition like ST_DWithin(geom1,geom2,100) = FALSE will give you what you want.